# Триггер с условием

Tags: mysql, триггер

мне необходимо создать триггер с условием, если errors = 0, то необходимо инсертить в другую таблицу id записи у которого errors = 0, где может быть ошибка?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `logs` AFTER UPDATE ON `data` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF(NEW.errors = 0) THEN
  INSERT into `logs` (`errors`) VALUES(NEW.errors);
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: VALUES(NEW.errors) = VALUES(NEW.id) ?

Comment: @splash58, Почему id? не доводилось с триггерами работать

Comment: еобходимо инсертить в другую таблицу id

Comment: `INSERT INTO logs (errors) VALUES (NEW.id);`

Comment: @Akina, Выдает ошибку синтаксиса около '' на строке 3

Comment: 1) Всегда цитируйте сообщение об ошибке полностью и без изменений. 2) Всегда указывайте точно код, который привёл к ошибке (а не "вон в том коде я поменял..."). 3) Оптимум - создайте fiddle, воспроизводящий проблему.